# how to convert a string to a ushort

Tags: c#, string, ushort

I have researched all of the questions that match my query and tried their solutions however none appear to work for me so I am asking how I convert a string to a `ushort` I have this set up all ready

```
public static string vid
{
    get { return "<vehicleid>"; }
}
```

I've tried to use this : `short[] result = vid.Select(c => (ushort)c).ToArray();`
    but when I go to put the vid ushort into this bit

```
[RocketCommand("vehicle", "This command spawns you a vehicle!", "<vehicleid>", AllowedCaller.Player)]
public void ExecuteCommandVehicle(IRocketPlayer caller, string[] command)
{
    UnturnedPlayer spawner = (UnturnedPlayer)caller;
    spawner.GiveVehicle(vid);
}
```

I get the following error :

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'ushort'    arena v by FridgeBlaster    C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\arena v by FridgeBlaster\arena v by FridgeBlaster\vehicle.cs    71  Active

Comment: i dont understand what u edited @m.rogalski

Comment: check [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45281231/revisions) to see what was edited.

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is `ushort.TryParse` or `ushort.Parse` methods.
I would suggest using this piece of code :

```
ushort[] result = vid.Where(i => ushort.TryParse(i, out short s)).Select(ushort.Parse);
```

Or if you do not use latest C# version :

```
ushort[] result = vid.Where(i => { ushort r = 0; return ushort.TryParse(i, out r); }).Select(ushort.Parse);
```

---

Okay so the problem ( as what your error says ) is that your `GiveVehicle` method accepts `ushort` as an argument and you're putting `string` type in it. Try doing something like this :

```
ushort val = 0;
if(ushort.TryParse(vid, out val))
{
    UnturnedPlayer spawner = (UnturnedPlayer)caller;
    spawner.GiveVehicle(val);
}
```

---

Based [on this source](https://github.com/RocketMod/Rocket/blob/master/Rocket.Core/Commands/RocketCommandManager.cs#L197) which is responsible for calling method marked with `RocketCommand` attribute. Your `<"vehicleid">` is/should be stored in a `command` array on first place. So to get this out and convert use something like this :

```
if(command.Length > 0)
{
    ushort val = 0;
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command[0]) && ushort.TryParse(command[0], out val))
    {
        UnturnedPlayer spawner = (UnturnedPlayer)caller;
        spawner.GiveVehicle(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: it says theres a problem with the short bit im gonna try the other one

Comment: the only problem I have with this is its for a game called unturned and people are supposed to do /vehicle <vehicleid> to spawn a certain vehicle and then it spawns it for them but if you are setting it to 0 it can't spawn anything

Comment: This "unturned" does not tells me much. All of the answers (examples) above are doing what you want ( convert `string` to `ushort` ) but since you've mentioned some "game engine" or whatever. You should supply some more information, how is this method called or what are you getting in the `command` parameter.

Comment: you can pick who calls it with ÀllowedCaller.player AllowedCaller.console or AllowedCaller.both I just set it to player because there is no point in using it in the console because it spawns it in game players call it using the /vehicle command which is the first "" in [RocketCommand]  one of the compulosasry variables is the <vehicleid> which is used in spanwer.GiveVehicle(vid); whihc will spawn the vehicle based on the id in game for the players that calls the command

Answer (score 2):

For a simple string to ushort conversion: `UInt16.Parse(string)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the line `short[] result = vid.Select(c => (ushort)c).ToArray();` it looks like there might be multiple IDs in a single string (each character, I assume).

If that's the case, try something like this:

```
ushort[] result = vid.ToCharArray().Select(c => (ushort) c).ToArray();
```

If you've got several actual numbers in the string separated by a character (e.g. "13,15,18"), give this a shot:

```
ushort[] result = vid.Split(separator).Select(str => ushort.Parse(str)).ToArray();
```

For either of these options, make sure you include using directives for the `System` and `System.Linq` namespaces.

---

With discussion on this and other answers, it looks like `command` is the result of tokenizing `"/vehicle <id>"`. In this case, the body of the `ExecuteCommandVehicle(IRocketPlayer, string[])` method should be similar to this:

```
ushort result = 0;
if (ushort.TryParse(command[1], out result)) {
  UnturnedPlayer spawner = caller as UnturnedPlayer;
  caller?.GiveVehicle(result);
}
```

Comment: it says cannot convert from ushort[] to ushort

Comment: @JonathanConnery How are you using `result`? It may help if you provide an example of the string you're trying to convert/parse in the question.

Comment: I will copy and paste it below UnturnedPlayer spawner = (UnturnedPlayer)caller;
                spawner.GiveVehicle(result);

Comment: `result` is an array - you'll need to figure out which element from the array you need. E.g. `spawner.GiveVehicle(result[0])`. If your `vid` variable is just a single number, use `ushort.TryParse` like Roman Ananyev or m.rogalski suggested.

Comment: thats where the problem comes its an id for something ingame where the number can range from 2-147

Answer (score 0):

Either you want to convert the string to a short:

```
Int16.Parse(...)
```

or

```
Int16.TryParse(...)
```

or you want to convert char to short by first converting string to array of chars:

```
vid.ToCharArray[..]
```

Comment: they all say it doesnt exist in the current context

Comment: Add `using System;` to the top of your file @JonathanConnery